# Fit plane into point set with known approximate distances to plane

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I have an interesting and relatively simple question, that I have not seen.

I have a set of N (N is large) points $p_i$ in 3D (on a regular grid, but that part is not too important). For each point I know the three coordinates and have a good guess for the signed distance $d_i$ to a plane (distance plus some noise). I want to fit the unknown plane into this data (=basically linearly approximate the zero level set of the signed distance function). The situation is usually pretty stable (meaning I have lots of points on either sides of the plane).

A simple approach could be to randomly sample pairs of points, one from each side of the plane for stability, then split the vector connecting them (difference $p_j - p_i$) according to their distances  to the plane ($d_i, d_j$, one is pos the other neg):

$q_{ij} := p_i + \frac{d_i}{d_i - d_j} (p_j-p_i) = \frac{d_i}{d_i - d_j} p_j - \frac{d_j}{d_i-d_j} p_i$

For each such pair, this provides an estimate of a point on the plane. Now I can just fit a plane to these points $q_{ij}$ by de-meaning and SVD.

The question is: is there a better way that directly considers all points, instead of random pairs, and solves this in a single step?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: If your plane is $ax+by+cz = 1$ solve the Normal Equation $A^T A\vec{a} = A^T \vec{1}$ where A is your N by 3 matrix of points (as rows), $\vec{1}$ is your N by 1 column of 1's and the solution $\vec{a}$ is the 3 by 1 vector giving the best least squares approximation to $(a, b, c)$.

Comment: Hi @Paul , thanks but I am not trying to fit a plane into a set of points. The points are on a regular grid, so this would find the mid plane of the grid (in fact all three mid-planes would be equally a solution). Your approach does not account for the known distances to the plane $d_i$.

Comment: I can't quite visualize what you are doing then sorry.

Comment: Given are a set of points $p_i$ and a noisy signed distance $d_i$ of each of these points to the unknown plane. Maybe I could simply try to solve $\alpha x_i + \beta y_i + \gamma z_i + \delta = d_i$ where  $(x_i,y_i,z_i) = p_i$ and $d_i$ the known (noisy) distance to the plane for point $p_i$. This should give me the 4 unknowns.

Comment: If $ax+by+cz=d$ is the plane then the distance of  $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ to the plane is $ax_i+by_i+cz_i - d = d_i$. This brings us back to my first suggestion where now each row of A is $(x_i,y_i,z_i, -1)$ and $\vec{1}$ on the right is replaced with the column of $d_i$ values. This will then have the least squares solution of a, b, c and d values.

Comment: Yes, I can solve those 4 variables, however, three should be enough to determine the plane. For a plane you really only need a unit normal vector and the value d (or $\delta$ in my equation, wanted to avoid confusion with the $d_i$). So all you really need is a vector in the normal direction and the length of this vector is $\delta$. That would mean solving for 4 variables could be problematic, as there could be multiple differenent solutions?

Comment: The solution I suggest takes all points into account. A is an N by 4 matrix  where N is your number of points.

Comment: Yes, and the solution is 4 variables in your suggestion. And I was saying that three are enough to specify a plane, so isn't there redundancy in your suggestion? And what does that mean for finding a non unique solution of the over-determined system?

Comment: Your distances are noisy though, so won't the best you can do be an "averaged" plane. The Normal Equation for this example will find a single "best " averaged plane in a least squares sense. Try it and see is all I can suggest.